# Getting the CURRENT value of a checkbox onclick

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onclick

From what I can tell from reading everything I can find here, this doesn't seem to be possible, but I just thought I'd ask.

What I want to do is prevent a checkbox from doing its default toggle action and run a function instead. This function needs to know the checkboxes CURRENT state- as opposed to the state it will be in after the click event has toggled it- and that toggle needs to be prevented.

So say I have this input for example

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="setDefault(this);return false;" />
```

And the setdefault function is something like this

```
function setDefault(el) {
    if(jQuery(el).is(':checked'))
        {
        alert('Turning current default off- setting default to Home settings');
        jQuery(el).prop('checked',false);
        return; 
        }
    else
        {
        alert('setting a new default');
        jQuery(el).prop('checked',false);
        return; 
        }
}
```

When that runs it gets the status the checkbox has been changed to, whreas what I need it to do is prevent the status from changing, find out its current status and then decide what to do.

I have tried every combination of preventDefault() and return false I can think of both in the function and the onclick event and have tried using the onchange event etc etc, but nothing seems to allow me to call a function that fires when the checkbox is clicked that allows the function to get the current value of the checkbox before it is changed by the click event.

Probably I just need to rethink this but if there is anything obvious I have missed I'd be most grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the change happened already, the state of the checkbox is the opposite of what it is *now*. That solves your first problem.

To reset the state, just set the checkbox's `checked` value to what it isn't now, which is what it was before.

(my, this sounds like something the Mad Hatter would say!)

Comment: Right, ok! Sure is Mad Hatterish! so I have added this to the start of my function -- jQuery(el).is(':checked') ? jQuery(el).prop('checked',false) : jQuery(el).prop('checked',true);-- that seems to do the trick ;)

Comment: Glad to help. Also, just FYI, if you find an answer or question helpful, or you think an answer adds useful information, you can up-vote to show your support as well.

Comment: Done, sorry, am a bit new round here :~

Comment: No worries. Everyone was new once, and there's nothing wrong with taking your time to learn the ropes and get familiar with everything. Welcome!